# React java script: IF function works only once on button click

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo

So I am using react native, and firebase db.

On register form button click i have function which creates user and also upload some info like city phone lalala:

```
   handleSignUp = () => {
    Fire.shared.createUser(this.state.email, this.state.password, this.state.name, this.state.avatar, this.state.mobile, this.state.pickerSelection, this.state.errorMessage)

    if (this.state.name == "") this.setState({ errorMessage: "Vartotojo vardas privalomas" });
        else  if (this.state.email == "") this.setState({ errorMessage: "El. pašto adresas privalomas" });
            else if (this.state.password == "") this.setState({ errorMessage: "Slaptažodis privalomas" });
                else  if (this.state.password2 == "") this.setState({ errorMessage: "Pakartokite slaptažodį" });
                    else  if (this.state.city == "") this.setState({ errorMessage: "Telefono nr. privalomas" });    
                        else  if (this.state.mobile == "") this.setState({ errorMessage: "Miestas privalomas" });    
                             else if ( this.state.password != this.state.password2) this.setState({ errorMessage: "Slaptažodžiai nesutampa" });
                                else { 
                                    Fire.shared.createUser(this.state.email, this.state.password, this.state.name, this.state.avatar, this.state.mobile, this.state.pickerSelection);
                                };
   };
```

So first time function works. any of these IFS. if I leave blank input I see error message nicely, but if I press button one more time it is just creating user anyway, even with empty values... like literaly this all works only once...

Here is my create user function:

```
   handleSignUp = () => {
    Fire.shared.createUser(this.state.email, this.state.password, this.state.name, this.state.avatar, this.state.mobile, this.state.pickerSelection, this.state.errorMessage)

    if (this.state.name == "") this.setState({ errorMessage: "Vartotojo vardas privalomas" });
        else  if (this.state.email == "") this.setState({ errorMessage: "El. pašto adresas privalomas" });
            else if (this.state.password == "") this.setState({ errorMessage: "Slaptažodis privalomas" });
                else  if (this.state.password2 == "") this.setState({ errorMessage: "Pakartokite slaptažodį" });
                    else  if (this.state.city == "") this.setState({ errorMessage: "Telefono nr. privalomas" });    
                        else  if (this.state.mobile == "") this.setState({ errorMessage: "Miestas privalomas" });    
                             else if ( this.state.password != this.state.password2) this.setState({ errorMessage: "Slaptažodžiai nesutampa" });
                                else { 
                                    Fire.shared.createUser(this.state.email, this.state.password, this.state.name, this.state.avatar, this.state.mobile, this.state.pickerSelection);
                                };
   };
```

Maybe it is because of ASYNC and AWAIT? Im using in only because of tutorial, im not sure what is that.

Comment: Can you please explain and show how this function is called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you call Fire.shared.createUser() two times, the first time is before your checks (so it will create user anyway), the second time is when your checks passed;

Comment: oh yeah. I see sorry. I copied and forgot to delete :D thanks for answer !!!!